# How to get the name given to transaction controller using beanshell preprocesssor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want to get the name given to transaction controller using BeanShell preprocessor in JMeter.
 Which I want to use to connect and display in dynaTrace later using header manager.

I tried something like this using BeanShell listener

```
String test = sampleResult.getSampleLabel();
log.info(test);
```

but I want to use the preprocessor.

```
log.info(sampler.getName());
```

This is used to get the name of sampler, in the similar way I want to get the name of transaction controller.

Specifically, I want to use BeanShell preprocessor .

Can somebody help me in this?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: thanks @KIril S....if not beanshell pre processor then,is there any way to get the transaction name..

Comment: JMeter doesn't give you any good way to get any element except the current one. What are you trying to achieve? It might be possible to find a workaround if you explain what the goal is

Comment: Im trying to get the aggregate report in dynaTrace,in the same way as we get in jmeter.For that im passing two values to dynaTrace PC=jmeter NA-sampler name/Transaction controller name .instead of adding NA to each of the  header manager i want to add a beanshell preprocessor which will take the transsaction controller name and put that variable in header manager

Comment: sampler.getName()  gives the sampler name of each samplers right in the same way,im trying to get

Comment: yes, there's no such thing. The method suggested below (traversing the tree) is decent workaround if you do it once per test run (e.g. on init), but very expensive otherwise, and likely not worth it for real load test. If it's for report (which probably means you need it for every single execution), why not hard-code it to actual transaction name? Or in other way: make transaction name a variable, and have the same variable assigned to `NA` parameter as you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot walk further than [Previous Result](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getPreviousResult()) or [Previous Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getPreviousSampler()) so I would state that it is not something you can implement easily. Looks like your test is not very well designed as normally people do not require knowing the name of the parent sampler controller.

Nevertheless you can get access to [JMeter Test Plan Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html) and figure out information from there. The example code will look something like:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.control.TransactionController;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Collection;

StandardJMeterEngine engine = ctx.getEngine();
Field test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
test.setAccessible(true);
HashTree testPlanTree = (HashTree) test.get(engine);

SearchByClass txnCtrlSearch = new SearchByClass(TransactionController.class);
testPlanTree.traverse(txnCtrlSearch);
Collection txnControllers = txnCtrlSearch.getSearchResults();

for (Object txnController : txnControllers) {
    log.info(((TransactionController) txnController).getName());
}
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell Transaction Controller Name]

Some information on using JMeter API from Beanshell scripts: [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Comment: Hi @shey can you explain me that how you implemented this code in your script to get transaction controller name in header manager.